# Automatically start python program at start-up

Tags: boot, python, xorg, gui

I am working on a project that needs a special GUI that takes up the full screen.

I know I can make the X-Window system start up on boot (using `raspi-config` then changing the setting) but is it possible to just load the bare minimum to display the GUI (created in Glade) and then automatically start the python script? I don't want to display the desktop ever, as it is a type of Virtual Operating System.

Comment: You can autostart programs using `sudo nano ~/.config/autostart/FullScreenApp.desktop` and then use pygtk  `gtk.Window.fullscreen()` (I didn't try)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawing directly on the screen (frame buffer) is actually much faster than using X when you are using Broadcom's [VideoCore (OpenVG)](http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_VideoCore_APIs) library. The major resources you need to look at, including examples and source code, are already pre-installed on Rapsberry Pi. For example, try this in console mode:

```
cd /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_triangle
sudo make
./hello_triangle
```

You will see a full screen GUI is shown. You may also want to look at a very nice [wrapper library](https://github.com/ajstarks/openvg) that makes using OpenVG much easier, which includes additional very nice examples.

For starting up a program automatically, you can add it in your `/etc/rc.local` file, just before `exit 0`, like this:

```
#....
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

/your/path/your_fancy_gui &>/dev/null &

exit 0
```

Note you need to use `&` to put the program in the background, or the system boot sequence would be stopped there until you program quits.

Comment: Perfect! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Will definitely include a reference to you in the final product somewhere somehow!

Answer (score -1):

You **need** some kind of window manager to have a GUI. You could make a text based UI instead! (ncurses may be helpful)

Comment: That I know, but I was hoping to find a slightly more in-depth answer if it is possible. I know that I need some kind of window manager, but I don't want to display any icons, menus, menu-bars, window border (Name, Icon, Buttons)s, etc. I just want to be able to display a window (blank, white) so that I can make a simple UI for the Virtual OS.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a window manager, or even X.

I'm starting up to the console and running a program via auto-login. The program simply draws the GUI on the framebuffer.

Comment: That's possible? Do you have any links to sites I could look at for info on this, or some of the code/special setup that you used? That would be great, thanks